# Can an object return an integer but have a custom type?

Tags: python, class, object, types, int

Is it possible to do this in Python:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = MyClass()

foo = Foo()  

assert foo.bar == 0
assert type(foo.bar) == MyClass
```

If 0 was a string then __repr__ could be used in MyClass. The the value would be '0' but the type would be MyClass. But since __repr__ can only return string, and foo.bar has to be an int __repr__ does not work. So is it possible to have MyClass() giving a value of 0 (int) but still keep its type as MyClass?

Comment: you could redefine `__eq__` to return `True` if argument is 0.

Comment: Why not just store the integer inside of MyClass? So you can just do something like `assert foo.bar.val == 0` and `assert type(foo.bar) == MyClass`

Comment: I dont' understand what any of this has to do with `__repr__`.... Anyway, objects don't return things. Objects are values. You cannot be an `int` and `MyClass`, unless `MyClass` derives from `int`

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, especially if you can't provide the necessary `__eq__` method for `MyClass`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Or unless you create a new class that multiply inherits from both `int` and `MyClass`, which might make sense if `MyClass` is designed to be used as .a mixin.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. Turned out doing just that worked just fine for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish what you are talking about using the [numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) package of the Python standard library, which implements [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/).  Specifically, you can derive `MyClass` from `numbers.Integral`, and override the special methods as necessary.